# Query with SUM of decimal values returns with unexpected value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm developing an application which uses a SQLite in-memory database and the anomaly is the following:

Used query:

```sql
SELECT FE1 
FROM DRC 
WHERE DTS >= '2021-04-21T17:04:44+02:00' 
AND DTS < '2021-04-21T17:20:09+02:00' 
AND (DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM NYN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM ESN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM SZN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM VBN WHERE CNC = '0') 
)
```

It returns with:

```
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
999999,99
0,09
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-999999,99
-0,09
```

The type of FE3 is Text, therefore all calculation should be cast to Decimal (with correction of decimal separator from comma to dot).

The expected sum of these values must be 0 after conversion.

But if I run the query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(FE1,',','.') AS DECIMAL))
FROM DRC
WHERE DTS >= '2021-04-21T17:04:44+02:00' 
AND DTS < '2021-04-21T17:20:09+02:00' 
AND (DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM NYN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM ESN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM SZN WHERE CNC = '0')
  OR DTS IN (SELECT DTS FROM VBN WHERE CNC = '0')
)
```

The result is **-1.31316482687716e-09** even if it should be **0**

If I run the same query in SQL Server, I get the proper 0 value.

What can be the problem?

Comment: At a guess, it's using floating point operations, which introduce an inaccuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but why it is behaving differently on SQLServer? And which type should I use for that instead?

Comment: Probably because SQL Server is a different database engine and does support fixed precision arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type that you cast the values of `FE1` is not the problem.
SQLite can do implicit conversion to a floating point number even if you don't do it explicitly:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(FE1,',','.')) result
FROM DRC
.......................................
```

will also return `-1.3131648268772E-9`.

The problem is with SQLite's precision of floating numbers arithmetic operations which as you found out is not good enough.

A workaround is to multiply all values by `100`, if you are sure that all values have at most 2 decimal places, before the aggregation and divide the final result again by by `100`:

```
SELECT SUM(REPLACE(FE1,',','.') * 100) / 100 result
FROM DRC
...................................................
```

will return `0`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=26183fe3022e907e1713a892da1f7fdb).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, now it is clear

Comment: To bo honest, it is not working for all case: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4979b8d48ee5d81b46521b9477da38dc)

Comment: @slt increase 100 to 1000: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4807499c0e46242f42488a87d2762df7. There is no solution, only workarounds.

Comment: Ok it is clear now. Thanks again the prompt response!

Comment: @slt or cast to in integer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=25848d0d3d467083294be002e69e81bd. Or both!